Modify the julia launcher in vscode
With julia v1.10.4 and suitesparse v5.0.0 (on Ubuntu Linux LTS 22.04), everytime julia runs, it shows the following error:
│   exception =
│    could not load symbol "SuiteSparse_config_malloc_func_set":
│    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsuitesparseconfig.so.5: undefined symbol: SuiteSparse_config_malloc_func_set

I solved this issue by setting the alias julia='LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" julia' in the .bashrc file. However, I am unsure how to set this configuration in VS Code. It is clear that I need to modify the Julia launcher in VS Code, but I have not been able to solve the problem yet.
I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue.
Update:

The problem does not exist with the debian system where the libcolmod version is 1.5.12 whereas the libcholmod version in ubuntu LTS22.04 is 1.5.10.
In the process of locating julia automatically the message in julia is as follows:

Juliaup found.
The current configuration value for 'julia.executablePath' is 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" $HOME/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.10.4+0.x64.linux.gnu/bin/julia'.
The identified Julia executable is "$HOME/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.10.4+0.x64.linux.gnu/bin/julia" with args "".```




(,untested) couldn't you make a bash  script that first set this env variable and then call the julia executable and set the julia extension in vscode to point to your script?

This is what is showing in the "OUTPUT" in VSCODE                                                   Trying to locate Julia binary... Juliaup found. The current configuration value for 'julia.executablePath' is 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH="" ~/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.10.4+0.x64.linux.gnu/bin/julia'. The identified Julia executable is "~/.julia/juliaup/julia-1.10.4+0.x64.linux.gnu/bin/julia" with args "".

I think this discussion on GitHub will help explain things. Make a custom wrapper script as shown and set VSCode up to run that instead?
